# How to set graph picture for Facebook apps

Tags: facebook, graph

In the past, an app had a graph picture just like users from the url

https://graph.facebook.com/APPID/picture

This came from the old app fan pages. Now that apps have migrated to regular fan pages, there are two problems.

1: Old apps still use the picture from the old inaccessible app page and there seems to be no way to change it.

2: New apps just get a question mark with no way to change it.

How can the graph picture be set for apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that has since been fixed by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a brand new app.  So I know this applies to new apps.

1. Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/summary`,
2. move your mouse over the icon and an action link appears saying "Edit" in the upper right corner of the default image.
3. Click that edit action link
4. Click [Browser...] to find the image on your local environment to upload
5. Select image
6. Wait for it to process.
7. It appears beside your app name on that basic page.

**EDIT**

How to get at this photo.

`http://graph.facebook.com/{APP ID}?fields=logo_url`

Comment: That changes the icon but it doesn't change the image that is from https://graph.facebook.com/APPID/picture

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood.  I haven't found a way yet to change the picture coming back from that call.  However to get at the picture I changed, see my notes above.

Comment: I am still unable to change the graph image for apps.